# Postgres Copy with null date and integer fields

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a java app that is streaming data from possibly large files into a postgres RDS via a JDBC connection.

I am using the following command which works for null integer types.

```
COPY tableName FROM STDIN with (format csv, delimiter E'\u0001', NULL '', QUOTE E'\u0005')
```

However this does not work for null date fields
(PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for date: "")

If I modify the command to

```
COPY tableName FROM STDIN with (format csv, delimiter E'\u0001', NULL '\N', QUOTE E'\u0005')
```

It works for date fields, but not for integer fields. (PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "\N")

I've seen similar questions on here addressing either nulls for integer fields or nulls for date fields, but not both, so I'm wondering if there is a way to specify null that will work with both integer and date fields (or a way to specify multiple different null strings for different data types)

I would really like to use COPY as the performance is much better than parsing the file and inserting each record, so hoping this is possible

Comment: @VaoTsun, thanks for the reply. I found another solution that I've put as the answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So with [Postgres 9.4+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) This is achievable using FORCE_NULL

based on the documentation

> Match the specified columns' values against the null string, even if it has been quoted, and if a match is found set the value to NULL. In the default case where the null string is empty, this converts a quoted empty string into NULL. This option is allowed only in COPY FROM, and only when using CSV format.

So my modified SQL is as follows:

```
COPY tableName FROM STDIN with (format csv, delimiter E'\u0001', null '', quote E'\u0005', force_null(dateField1, dateField2,...,dateFieldN));
```

Comment: Big thx! long time searching answer! My code: `copy TableName(place_id,osm_type,problem_column) FROM 'D:\File.csv' WITH (format csv, DELIMITER ';', header true, force_null (problem_column), ENCODING 'UTF8' );`

Comment: UPD it works for _postgresql version 11_. check version `select version();` for another versions at bottom of [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-copy.html)